# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have this line using OpenCV:

```
xsize = random.uniform(params['reshape_x_limits'][0],params['reshape_x_limits'][1])
ysize = random.uniform(params['reshape_x_limits'][0],params['reshape_x_limits'][1])
cv2.resize(fg,0,fg,xsize,ysize)
```

Which gives the error

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

However according to the documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

None of the arguments should be tuples. What is causing this error? I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.3.0.10.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you posted, you could see a sample there:

```
resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation);
```

the parameter `Size()` is a tuple `(width, length)`

Another example you can [find in this tutorial about geometric transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html), for instance:

```
res = cv2.resize(img,(2*width, 2*height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d), dsize is a required parameter so it has to be supplied. Strangely, d=0 gave me the same error as you.
Specifying dsize=None solved the issue for me. Following is the snippet:

```
a=cv2.imread('lighthouse2.bmp',0)
b=cv2.resize(a,None,fx=0.5,fy=0.5,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow('',b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and OpenCv 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Very old post, but I wasted 30 min, so if someone is having issues...
The cv2 documentation may be outdated...

the use in newer versions is

```
destImage = cv.resize(srcImage, Size(), fx, fy, interpolation)
```

Noice that the **second** parameter is the tuple (can be put as **None** if you have fx, fy)

Hope it helps to whoever is looking.